# Indexing by Database engine tuning advisor

Tags: sql-server, performance

We are indexing a database with tuning advisor.Suppose we have two queries taking two different set of data from a single table.

When we analyse the two queries we got two types of recommendations such as

```
 1. Index three columns c1,c2 and c3 in the table, here c1 is primary key.
 2. Index three columns c2,c3 and c4 in the table.
```

In this case how we have to proceed. Whether we have to create two indices? Please give your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can analyze both queries at the same time using the same database engine tuning session, and you should get one or more index recommendations that are compatible with one another.  The recommendation for database tuning advisor is to run a profiler against your application for a period of time, like 5-10 minutes depending on the load and number of queries.  Then run the entire results together in the tuning advisor to get a list of recommendations.

Hope this helps!

**Edit**

See this link for more information: http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1872.

Comment: @mellamokb: Actually we analysed the query as separate work load file. For this we took the query part from stored procedure and then replaced the variables value with appropriate value in the table. Is it a right way?

Comment: @mahesh: That's fine.  My only point is you want to analyze all of your queries in a single workload, not one query at a time.  That way, the recommendations will apply to the entire workload.  If you analyze query by query, you may get overlapping index recommendations as you are seeing, and neither one may actually be the best.

Comment: @mellamokb: So can i copy all script in to one single .sql file and analyse it?

Comment: @mellamokb: Now we got a list of recommendations. Can i just run the whole recommendations. Is there any chance to affect it badly to the db.

Comment: @mahesh: Indexes speed up the performance of reading records at the cost of slowing down writing.  If you have a table that takes many writes, you may notice a performance hit.  The best thing to do is compare how fast the application is before you apply the recommendations, and after you apply the recommendations to see if it is better.

Comment: @mellamokb: If it is not up to our expectations what is the best method to drop these all recommendations from the db.

Comment: @mahesh: I would definitely make a backup of the database before applying the recommendations!  Then you can just revert to the backup.