# Creating index on group of columns or separate index for each column, which is better?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I've used **Database engine tuning advisor** to generate Index recommendations for **multiple queries** separately. After doing so i got separate recommendation for each query. As a result i noticed that the column used in one recommendation is used for another since the queries depends on the same table.

Can i create one effective recommendation after running the multiple queries together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  It is recommended that you run an entire workload through the database engine tuning advisor.  See this similar question: [Indexing by Database engine tuning advisor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113927/indexing-by-database-engine-tuning-advisor/5113941#5113941)

Comment: Thanks for your reply... Since i have to tune a system which has numerous queries, i used database engine tuning advisor to create indices. Does the indexing done using database engine tuning advisor consider all the things mentioned in the other answer (answer by marc_s) after running it by giving the complete queries as one sql file (ie, in one database engine tuning advisor session)?

Answer (score 1):

It depends - fewer, but wider indices are typically better - **if** your queries actually do use those columns in the wide index!

If you have five queries, and each of them uses a different column in the `WHERE` clause, then a single, wide index won't be much help.

But if you have queries that all use some or the same columns (two, three columns), then a single, wide index on those three columns is better to use.

But be aware: the order of your columns in the index is important!

If you create an index on `(col1, col2, col3)` it can help with queries that have `WHERE col1 = value1` or `WHERE col1 = value1 AND col2 = value2` conditions.

It cannot however be used for a query with a WHERE clause like `WHERE col3 = value3`

Comment: Thanks for your reply... Since i have to tune a system which has numerous queries, i used database engine tuning advisor to create indices. Does the indexing done using database engine tuning advisor consider all the things you mentioned after running it by giving the complete queries as one sql file (ie, in one database engine tuning advisor session)?

Comment: Please correct my thinking process then. I understand that wide indexes are better if number and order of columns a query retrieves match the wide index. Why is it better? Is it about one index file vs many?
Then, is it true that having separate index per each column would be an ideal scenario (in case I have all sorts of queries) but I may get a performance hit because of sql server having to deal with many separate indexes? Is the amount of index files the main consideration?